# how to get data from JSON array SwiftyJSON?

Tags: ios, arrays, json, swifty-json

I would like to be able to get some data from a JSON array: [here](https://api.tfl.gov.uk/journey/journeyresults/1000003/to/1000012)
so below, I am trying to show EARLIEST > DATE

```
func parseJSONtowns() {
    let url = NSURL(string: "https://api.tfl.gov.uk/journey/journeyresults/\(selectedStation)/to/\(selectedStation1)")
    let jsonData = NSData(contentsOfURL: url!)
    let readableJSON = try! NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData!, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]
    let object = JSON(readableJSON)
    let searchCriteria = object["earliest"]
    for option in searchCriteria.arrayValue {
        let commonName = option["date"].stringValue
        commonNameArray.append(commonName)
    }
    selectedStation = selectedStation.stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString("%20", withString: " ")
    NumberOfRows = commonNameArray.count
    NSLog("\(url)")
    NSLog("number of rows: \(NumberOfRows)")
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The `date` of `earliest` is in a dictionary `timeAdjustments` in a dictionary `searchCriteria`

```
let object = JSON(readableJSON)
let earliest = object["searchCriteria"]["timeAdjustments"]["earliest"]["date"].stringValue
print(earliest)
```

Comment: Thanks, changed date to time now it says the same for each whereas should be a different time, when I add it inside the for loop, it's the same?!

 `NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(jsonData!, options: []) as! [String:AnyObject]
let object = JSON(readableJSON)
let searchCriteria = object["journeys"]
let earliest = object["searchCriteria"]["timeAdjustments"]["earliest"]["time"].stringValue
  for option in searchCriteria.arrayValue {
  let arrivalDateTime = option["arrivalDateTime"].stringValue
  arrivalArray.append(arrivalDateTime)
  earliestArray.append(earliest)
}`

Comment: There is only one `earliest` key in the entire text and you get only a different `arrivalDateTime` in the repeat loop. Maybe you mean `startDateTime`